# Android: ListView in ArrayAdapter changes during the scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This is getView() of my Adapter - very simple implementation with View Holder pattern:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Exercise exercise = mList.getItem(position);

        ViewExerciseHolder viewExerciseHolder;

            if(convertView == null) {

                viewExerciseHolder = new ViewExerciseHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
                ...
                viewExerciseHolder.inputsLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputs);
                convertView.setTag(viewExerciseHolder);

            } else {
                viewExerciseHolder = (ViewExerciseHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            for (int i=0; i<exercise.nbSeries; i++) {

                ItemExerciseNbRepWeightView view = new ItemExerciseNbRepWeightView(getContext());

                view.setNbRep(exercise.nbReps);
                view.setWeight(exercise.weight);
                ...

                viewExerciseHolder.inputsLayout.addView(view);
            }
     }
```

The problem is the **inputsLayout** : the data added into are not correct and during the scrolling these data change...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested `Layout` is recycled, which means it may contain Views which were added in a previous call to `getView()`. You have to clear the recycled 'inputsLayout' of all `View`s you added earlier.

One way to do this is to call `removeAllViews()`.